# How to count Y/N answers in Python?

Tags: python, forms

I've been trying to make a form using y/n as answers for each of the questions. I've been wondering if I could do the same thing [like this](https://www.adamsmith.haus/python/answers/how-to-count-the-number-of-true-booleans-in-a-list-in-python), but for y/n questions instead of true/false statements.

Here's the code I've been working on.

```
print('Are You Ready for Omicron?')
print('Here\'s a test to make sure you\'re ready')
print('Note: please answer in y or n')
print('')
faceMask = input('Do you have a face mask? ')
faceShield = input('Do you have a face shield? ')
alcohol = input('Do you have alcohol in hand? ')

booleanList = [faceMask, faceShield, alcohol]
yCount = sum(booleanList)
print(yCount)
```

Based on the code, I was expecting to count the y answers but ended up with an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File [REDACTED], line 14, in <module>
    yCount = sum(booleanList)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Any simple yet good ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Hint: If you get an error it always makes sense to include it in the question...

Comment: do something like `faceMask = input('Do you have a face mask? ').upper() == 'Y'`

Comment: You can `import Counter from collections` and use it

Comment: The example you provided uses the nature of how `True` and `False` literals evaluate to 1 and 0 respectively and hence can be added. This doesn't work for 'Y' and 'N' directly unless you use something like what @SembeiNorimaki suggested

Comment: In real life, what is the sum of eg 'Y + N + Y' ? Python has no magic to make the sum of something like that. Read some books Ethan, really the best way to make things easy for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save one list comprehension and use less memory than Bluehorn's code, you could try this:

```
print('Are You Ready for Omicron?')
print('Here\'s a test to make sure you\'re ready')
print('Note: please answer in y or n')
print('')
faceMask = input('Do you have a face mask? ').lower() == 'y'
faceShield = input('Do you have a face shield? ').lower() == 'y'
alcohol = input('Do you have alcohol in hand? ').lower() == 'y'

booleanList = [faceMask, faceShield, alcohol]
yCount = sum(booleanList)
print(yCount)
```

Same caveat as Bluehorn's code, if input is not `'y'`, it will be ignored and hence not only `'n'` but any other character other than 'y' or 'Y' will be considered as `False`.

Comment: `lower(input('Do you have a face mask? ')) == 'y'` already returns a boolean. the if else is not necessary

Comment: I like your answer, because it makes booleanList actually a list of booleans.

Answer (score 2):

Your code basically resolves to

```py
yCount = sum(["y", "n", "y"])
```

This will raise this error:

```py
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

So you have to turn the elements into numbers to sum them:

```py
>>> booleanList = ["y", "n", "y"]
>>> yCount = sum(1 for answer in booleanList if answer == "y")
>>> yCount
2
```

This will sum the values in `booleanList` as follows:

- if `value != "y"`, it is ignored
- other values are summed by replacing them with 1

If you want to avoid higher language features like the generator expression above (`1 for answer in ...`), you can write this as follows:

```py
for i in range(len(booleanList)):
    booleanList[i] = booleanList[i] == "y"
yCount = sum(booleanList)
```

This relies on the fact that `True` is considered to be `1` in arithmetic expressions:

```py
>>> print(True + False + True)
2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put the awnsers in a list then count the totalt of y or no in the list.

```
print('Are You Ready for Omicron?')
print('Here\'s a test to make sure you\'re ready')
print('Note: please answer in y or n')
print('')
awnser_list = [] #empty list to fill
faceMask = input('Do you have a face mask? ')
faceMask = faceMask.lower() #make sure that all awnsers is in lower case.
faceShield = input('Do you have a face shield? ')
faceShield = faceShield.lower()
alcohol = input('Do you have alcohol in hand? ')
alcohol = alcohol.lower()
awnser_list.append(faceMask) #append the awnsers to the list
awnser_list.append(faceShield)
awnser_list.append(alcohol)
result = awnser_list.count("y") #count totalt of y in the list
print('Total of y: ',result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with the example you cited, you could do this:

```
print('Are You Ready for Omicron?')
print('Here\'s a test to make sure you\'re ready')
print('Note: please answer in y or n')
print('')
faceMask = input('Do you have a face mask? ')
if faceMask == "y":
    faceMask = True
else:
    faceMask = False
faceShield = input('Do you have a face shield? ')
if faceShield == "y":
    faceShield = True
else:
    faceShield = False
alcohol = input('Do you have alcohol in hand? ')
if alcohol == "y":
    alcohol = True
else:
    alcohol = False
booleanList = [faceMask, faceShield, alcohol]
yCount = sum(booleanList)
print(yCount)
```

This is not a recommended solution but I wanted to remind you to use if/else